# Non-static member function must be called

Tags: c++, gnu

Compiling on 64-bit Mac w/ -std=gnu++0x gives me the errors:

```
.../include/utils/common_types.h:93:37: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
    bool valid_min = StringToNumber(min, &min_)
                                    ^~~
.../include/utils/common_types.h:94:43: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
        && Fraction::FromFloatPointString(min, &min_fract_);
                                          ^~~
.../include/utils/common_types.h:95:37: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
    bool valid_max = StringToNumber(max, &max_)
                                    ^~~
.../include/utils/common_types.h:96:43: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
        && Fraction::FromFloatPointString(max, &max_fract_);
                                          ^~~
```

It compiles fine on 32-bit Ubuntu.

```
  BasicRange(const std::string& min_str, const std::string& max_str)
      : min_(0),
        max_(0) {
    bool valid_min = StringToNumber(min, &min_)
        && Fraction::FromFloatPointString(min, &min_fract_);
    bool valid_max = StringToNumber(max, &max_)
        && Fraction::FromFloatPointString(max, &max_fract_);
    assert(valid_min && valid_max);
  }
```

Comment: So what are `min` and `max`? And how are `StringToNumber` and `FromFloatPointString` declared? It sounds like they're functions, and that you probably want to call them. Or maybe you meant `min_` and `max_`.

Comment: They're member functions of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have `min` and `max` as member functions of the class.

Change the code to:

```
BasicRange(const std::string& min_str, const std::string& max_str)
    : min_(0),
      max_(0) {
  bool valid_min = StringToNumber(min(), &min_)
      && Fraction::FromFloatPointString(min(), &min_fract_);
  bool valid_max = StringToNumber(max(), &max_)
      && Fraction::FromFloatPointString(max(), &max_fract_);
  assert(valid_min && valid_max);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wonder how this code could be compiled on 32-bit Ubuntu.

It seems that the valid code should look the following way

```
  BasicRange(const std::string& min_str, const std::string& max_str)
      : min_(0),
        max_(0) {
    bool valid_min = StringToNumber(min_str, &min_)
        && Fraction::FromFloatPointString(min_str, &min_fract_);
    bool valid_max = StringToNumber(max_str, &max_)
        && Fraction::FromFloatPointString(max_str, &max_fract_);
    assert(valid_min && valid_max);
  }
```

That is instead of `min` and `max` there must be `min_str` and `max_str`

Also it is a very stupid idea to use last underscore in variable names. Do not copy the behaviour of some idiots even if they are well-known.

Comment: @JuJo The problem is that it is very difficult to understand where there is used for example max and where max_ and is there a typo or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments are called `min_str` and `max_str`, but in the code below you don't use that, you use `min` and `max`. These are presumably getters for the `min_` and `max_` properties, so when the compiler sees them, it complains that you're referencing member functions without calling them.